# Inequality with fractions

Tags: inequality

I have this inequality to solve:

```
1 / (2 - x) <= x
```

I worked out the critical values to be 1 and 2.
The answer is x > 2 or x = 1.
The problem I have is what is the inequality read >=
I would get the same critical values but different values for x, which satisfies the inequality. I noticed that with some working out methods, you can lose critical values in the process e.g.

if I did the inequality as follows:

```
1 / (2 - x) <= x
1 <= x(2 - x)
0 <= -x^2 + 2x - 1
0 <= (1 - x)^2
```

Hence, I end up with x = 1 being the only critical value.

Are there any rules for the working process for solving the inequality in this situation without losing critical values?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2-x}\le x$ is not equivalent to $1\le x(2-x)$, unless you assume that $2-x>0$.

Comment: Yes. Please could you elaborate on that and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because the original function is not defined at $x=2$. Whenever you do a problem like this you need to treat points where the function is undefined (at any step of the manipulation) separately.

I would do the manipulation that you've shown, getting $(x-1)^2\geq 0$, and so $1$ is a point I need to investigate. Additionally, the original fraction was undefined at $x=2$, so I need to investigate that as well. I notice that the inequality holds for $1$ but not for $0.5\pm 1$, and that the inequality holds for $x>2$. Thus the critical points are $\{1,2\}$ and the solution set is $\{1\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x>2\}$

Comment: I can still get x = 2 using another working out process but it will evaluate the fraction to undefined.

Comment: Can you post your solution to the inequality. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Points where one side of the inequality is undefined are also critical values (assuming that means "points where the truth of the inequality may switch")

Comment: Not obtaining a critical value can result in an incorrect solution.

Comment: If x = 2 was not calculated as a critical value because another form of working was used...then x = 1 would be used as the solution, which is only partially correct.

Comment: I added more to my post

Comment: Thank you. Also could you post a solution to the inequality if the relationship was >= instead of <=?

Comment: You do it the same way. The "=" changes when it evaluates to "true" not the critical points. So you'd conclude it doesn't hold for $1$ being the only difference